# How to stop image overlaping image when onMouseOver event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to figure out on how to use onmouseover and onmouseout using javascript for html scripting.

This is my html code:

```
<section class="col-md-4">
   <img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="images/alpha.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100">
</section>
```

this is my javascript:

```
function bigImg(x) {
   x.style.height = "200px";
   x.style.width = "200px";
   //x.style.zIndex = "1000px";
   //x.style.opacity = "1px";
}


function normalImg(x) {
   x.style.height = "100px";
   x.style.width = "100px";
   //x.style.zIndex = "1000px";
   //x.style.opacity = "1px";
}
```

So I managed to get it done. But my big image is being overlap with one another small image whenever I try to hover it. I wanted make it as if the hover is not being overlap by another picture.

Comment: unclear what you expect to happen or how when you change the size it somehow overlaps and does not push it down

Comment: If i understand correctly, some other image goes over your image when you increase size. You have CSS issue, not JS issue. Try setting z-index to 9999 for example (bigger index than that img at least), or maybe you need position absolute for your image, depends on the result you need.

Comment: Like when I try to hover it, but some parts of the picture from the big Image is being blocked or cover by the small image? I have two same HTML codes so in total there are 3 images.

Comment: Hi, @NemanjaG I was told to not use css as practice.

Comment: @fulniz you are using CSS in JS by changing the height, you can do the same for z-index

Comment: function bigImg(x) {
   x.style.height = "200px";
   x.style.width = "200px";
   x.style.zIndex = "9999px";
   //x.style.opacity = "1px";
}

Hi, I tried to edit like this, but still the same result.